# Nginx location match working only when matching root

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to configure nginx so I can have two locations. One for my node API and the other for my Jenkins CI.

`http://my_ip/api` should point to my node server and `http://my_ip/jenkins` should point to my jenkins CI

I have this server block.

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name my_ip_address;

location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /jenkins {

   proxy_set_header        Host $host;
   proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

   proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
   proxy_read_timeout  90;

}
}
```

That config is not working. But if I use any of those locations matching to root it works.

This works with no problem. And the same if I use the location block of my node api with `/` only.

```
location / {

   proxy_set_header        Host $host;
   proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

   proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
   proxy_read_timeout  90;

}
```

But if I change `/` to `/jenkins` it doesn't work anymore.

I know I'm missing some basic pice of knowledge here, but I can't figure this out since everywhere I look seems to suggests that should be working ok.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, after some more research on the subject I've noticed that the problem with that setup was that the location /api was not connecting to `http://127.0.0.1:1234/` it was trying to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:1234/api` and the same with jenkins.

So the solution is adding trailing slashes to both the location and proxy_pass.

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234/;
....

location /jenkins/ {
   proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080/;
   proxy_read_timeout  90;

....
```

So that did the trick.

Comment: You just saved my day!

Comment: If I could give +100 on this.. I would do it .. great thanks